# NUnit.3.13.3.nupkg doesn't exist. Unable to neither install a nuget package nor launch a project on ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I have a fresh Monogame mgdesktopgl project, try to launch it or install a package via Rider — and get an error:

`/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/6.0.116/NuGet.targets(130,5): error : The local source '/path/to/NUnit.3.13.3/NUnit.3.13.3.nupkg' doesn't exist. [/tmp/72ddfe2e-e24d-496e-ae34-4cfebefde81f/restore.csproj] [/anotherPath/to//testProj/testProj.csproj]

I have the nupkg in the required folder.
This error also occurs after "dotnet restore" and "dotnet tool restore" commands with the following log:

`Package "dotnet-mgcb" failed to restore, due to Microsoft.DotNet.ToolPackage.ToolPackageException: The tool package could not be restored. at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ProjectRestorer.Restore(FilePath project, PackageLocation packageLocation, String verbosity) at Microsoft.DotNet.ToolPackage.ToolPackageInstaller.InstallPackageToExternalManagedLocation(PackageLocation packageLocation, PackageId packageId, VersionRange versionRange, String targetFramework, String verbosity) at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Restore.ToolRestoreCommand.InstallPackages(ToolManifestPackage package, Nullable 1 configFile) Package "dotnet-mgcb-editor-windows" failed to restore, due to Microsoft.DotNet.ToolPackage.ToolPackageException: The tool package could not be restored. at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ProjectRestorer.Restore(FilePath project, PackageLocation packageLocation, String verbosity) at Microsoft.DotNet.ToolPackage.ToolPackageInstaller.InstallPackageToExternalManagedLocation(PackageLocation packageLocation, PackageId packageId, VersionRange versionRange, String targetFramework, String verbosity) at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Restore.ToolRestoreCommand.InstallPackages(ToolManifestPackage package, Nullable 1 configFile)`

I've tried "dotnet add package NUnit", and "nuget install Nunit" in the required folder, reinstalled dotnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by writing `dotnet new nugetconfig` in console. It was found in https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/nuget-targets-local-source-does-not-exist/

Comment: Then please click the tickbox to set this is the accepted answer.